# Ошибка при подключении boost "libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.lib" пакетным менеджером Conan

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, conan, cmakelists

Conaninfo.txt

```
[settings]
    arch=x86_64
    build_type=Release
    compiler=Visual Studio
    compiler.runtime=MD
    compiler.version=16
    os=Windows

[requires]
    boost/1.Y.Z

[options]


[full_settings]
    arch=x86_64
    arch_build=x86_64
    build_type=Release
    compiler=Visual Studio
    compiler.runtime=MD
    compiler.version=16
    os=Windows
    os_build=Windows

[full_requires]
    boost/1.77.0:37050c911e5419517ec6e0761c16c6e262b3e2a3
    bzip2/1.0.8:d16a91eadaaf5829b928b12d2f836ff7680d3df5
    zlib/1.2.11:3fb49604f9c2f729b85ba3115852006824e72cab

[full_options]
    boost:asio_no_deprecated=False
    boost:buildid=None
    boost:bzip2=True
    boost:debug_level=0
    boost:diagnostic_definitions=False
    boost:error_code_header_only=False
    boost:extra_b2_flags=None
    boost:filesystem_no_deprecated=False
    boost:header_only=False
    boost:i18n_backend=deprecated
    boost:i18n_backend_iconv=off
    boost:i18n_backend_icu=False
    boost:layout=system
    boost:lzma=False
    boost:magic_autolink=False
    boost:multithreading=True
    boost:namespace=boost
    boost:namespace_alias=False
    boost:numa=True
    boost:pch=True
    boost:python_executable=None
    boost:python_version=None
    boost:segmented_stacks=False
    boost:shared=False
    boost:system_no_deprecated=False
    boost:visibility=hidden
    boost:without_atomic=False
    boost:without_chrono=False
    boost:without_container=False
    boost:without_context=False
    boost:without_contract=False
    boost:without_coroutine=False
    boost:without_date_time=False
    boost:without_exception=False
    boost:without_fiber=False
    boost:without_filesystem=False
    boost:without_graph=False
    boost:without_graph_parallel=True
    boost:without_iostreams=False
    boost:without_json=False
    boost:without_locale=False
    boost:without_log=False
    boost:without_math=False
    boost:without_mpi=True
    boost:without_nowide=False
    boost:without_program_options=False
    boost:without_python=True
    boost:without_random=False
    boost:without_regex=False
    boost:without_serialization=False
    boost:without_stacktrace=False
    boost:without_system=False
    boost:without_test=False
    boost:without_thread=False
    boost:without_timer=False
    boost:without_type_erasure=False
    boost:without_wave=False
    boost:zlib=True
    boost:zstd=False
    bzip2:build_executable=True
    bzip2:shared=False
    zlib:shared=False

[recipe_hash]


[env]
```

Conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
boost/1.77.0

[generators]
cmake
cmake_find_package
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(boost_example)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR};${CMAKE_MDOULE_PATH}")
set(PROJECT_NAME "boost_example")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC  ${Boost_LIBRARY})
endif()
```

main.cpp

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator begin("./");
}
```

При сборке проекта в Microsoft Visual studio 2019 выдает ошибку:

```
Ошибка  LNK1104 не удается открыть файл "libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.lib"  boost_example   C:\Users\Dolba\Desktop\boost\build\LINK 1
```

Я как понимаю версии библиотек которые нужны boost отличаются от тех, которые подгрузил Conan.
Почему так происходит и как решить эту проблему? Разве Conan не должен давать корректные версии обнаружив мой компилятор? Спасибо.

Comment: `build_type=Release`, а сборка проекта видимо Debug c автоматической простановкой директив линкера, оттого автоматически линкуется не та библиотека. Это можно отключить директивой препроцессора `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`. Однако будет лучше самостоятельно скачать исходники boost и собрать для него 4 конфигурации.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы! Спасибо большое! Я в CMakeLists.txt добавил add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB) и все заработало.